# New Member Form, how to change default setting of Record Contributions

Tags: civimember

When adding a New Member and selecting a membership type that is 'paid' the 'Record Contribution' checkbox is auto ticked.

I can see why.  However this organisation processes contributions in batch and only want then to apply when banked, so have to untick this on each new member.

I looked, but couldn't see and admin option to change this behaviour, is there one? Or is there a simple code based override to stop the auto ticking on that box?